# Inserting individual values from an array into a table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a table using a for loop in my code and have various variables in multiple arrays. I want to be able to put the values from the array individually into each table cell going down in a column. For code I have this:

```
function tableCreate() {
 for (rownum = 1; rownum <= 7; rownum++) {
     document.write("<tr>");
     for (colnum = 1; colnum <= 7; colnum++) {  
     if (rownum == 1 + colnum == 1) {
         document.write("<td>" + id[0] + "</td>");
     }
     }
     document.write("</tr>");
 }
}

var id = new Array("1022", "1112", "1230", "554", "1355", "1600");
var title = new Array("Prof.", "Prof.", "Prof.", "Prof.", "Asst. Prof.", "Asst. Prof.");
var name = new Array("Catherine Adler", "Michael Li", "Maria Sanchez", "Robert Hope", "Wayne Li", "Kate Howard");
var position = new Array("Department Chair", "Asst. Chair", "TA Supervisor");
var er = new Array(2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3);
var yoe = new Array(18, 12, 10, 23, 8, 5);
var cs = new Array(85000, 70000, 62000, 55000, 50000, 45000);
```

The above code is all part of an external JavaScript document. I tryed using if statements to produce what I wanted but that failed. Now I'm lost and some help would be appreciated. To reitterate, I want to get say this array: var id = new Array("1022", "1112", "1230", "554", "1355", "1600");

into a table column and have each variable in that array take a cell in that column.

Comment: just to check, you want each row to contain an id, title, name, position, er, yoe, cs in that order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so clear but I think what you want is this:

```
function tableCreate() {
 for (rownum = 1; rownum <= 7; rownum++) {
     document.write("<tr>");
     for (colnum = 1; colnum <= 7; colnum++) {  
       if (colnum == 1) {
         document.write("<td>" + id[(colnum-1)] + "</td>");
       }
     }
     document.write("</tr>");
 }
}
```

---

I expect this is really what you want:

```
// constants
var colCount=7;
var rowCount=7;

// input data
var id = new Array("1022", "1112", "1230", "554", "1355", "1600");
var title = new Array("Prof.", "Prof.", "Prof.", "Prof.", "Asst. Prof.", "Asst. Prof.");
var name = new Array("Catherine Adler", "Michael Li", "Maria Sanchez", "Robert Hope", "Wayne Li", "Kate Howard");
var position = new Array("Department Chair", "Asst. Chair", "TA Supervisor");
var er = new Array(2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3);
var yoe = new Array(18, 12, 10, 23, 8, 5);
var cs = new Array(85000, 70000, 62000, 55000, 50000, 45000);

// make a special column.
var complicatedName;
for(index = 0; index < rowCount;index++)
{
   complicatedName[index] = title[index]+' '+name[index]+' - '+position[index];
}
colCount = colCount - 2

// create the column array.
var collist = [id,complicatedName,er,yoe,cs];

// make the table.
function tableCreate() {
 for (rownum = 1; rownum <= rowCount; rownum++) {
     document.write("<tr>");
     for (colnum = 1; colnum <= colCount; colnum++) {  
         document.write("<td>" + (collist[(colnum-1)])[(rownum-1)] + "</td>");
     }
     document.write("</tr>");
 }
}
```

Comment: This was actually very close to what I needed and it helped quite a bit. The table has headers that are id, name, title, postion etc. I don't need all the first values from each array in one column, but all the values in say the id array in the first column.

Comment: Oh wait I'm a lier, I messed it up. This is what I wanted thank you very much.

Comment: @michael -- please thank me by accepting the answer (check mark on left of answer).  Good luck.

Comment: I do have one more issue if your still available. I was required to create arrays for the name, position, and title variables however I am required to include them all in column. So the column known as name will have the title then the name followed by the position all in one column. Is it possible to combine the 3 into one and do basically the same thing spanning them down the name column?

Comment: @michael - ok there is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code.

Change this:

```
if (rownum == 1 + colnum == 1) {
```

...to this:

```
if (rownum == 1 && colnum == 1) {
```